# How to access encrypted Ubuntu installation from an other computer?

Tags: encryption, cryptsetup

So, I recycled an old compy, and I'm left with it's old HD.  It was an ubuntu 17.10 installation, encrypted with the 16.04 stock installation encrypter.

I know the passphrase, and used the following command...

```
> sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc1 usbdisk --type plain -c aes-cbc-plain
```

and any attempts to mount it error with `

```
> sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/         
mount: /mnt: /dev/sdc1 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

I don't know what to do next.

Comment: I get an error with `umount: /dev/sdc1: not mounted.`

Comment: To document my steps, I am plugging in the HD, running `sudo umount /dev/sdc1/`, `sudo cryptsetup ...`, and finally `sudo mount -o ro ...` and i am getting `already mounted or mount point busy.`  Am I doing it in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1):

Per the man page for `cryptsetup`:

> `cryptsetup open --type plain /dev/sda10 e1` maps the raw
>   encrypted device `/dev/sda10` to the mapped (decrypted) device
>   `/dev/mapper/e1`, which can then be mounted, `fsck`-ed or have a
>   filesystem created on it.

So it seems the commands you need are:

```
sudo cryptsetup open /dev/sdc1 usbdisk --type plain -c aes-cbc-plain
sudo mkdir /mnt/usbdisk
sudo mount /dev/mapper/usbdisk /mnt/usbdisk
```